# Generate jointly distributed random coefficients with given mean and variance from $N(0,1)$ and some matrix $L$

Tags: random-variable, joint-distribution

Suppose $\beta_1 \sim N(m_1,s_1^2)$, $\beta_2 \sim N(m_2,s_2^2)$ and $cov(\beta_1,\beta_2) = s_{12}$. Now generate draws of these random coefficients from draws of two independent standard normal distributed variables $z_1$ and $z_2$. Give the $2\times 2$ matrix $L$ that satisfies:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}\beta_1\\\beta_2\end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}m_1\\m_2\end{bmatrix} + L \begin{bmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Hint: make a guess and verify that L is Cholesky decomposition of 
$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} s_1^2 & s_{12} \\
s_{12} & s_2^2\end{bmatrix}$$
by computing $LL'$.

What I tried is to substitute
$$L = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\
c & d\end{bmatrix}$$
carry out the matrix multiplication and addition to get:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1\\\beta_2\end{bmatrix} \sim 
\begin{bmatrix} m_1 + az_1 + bz_2\\
m_2 + cz_1 + dz_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

My understanding is that this means that $\beta_1$ is distributed as $m_1 + az_1 + bz_2$ and $\beta_2$ as $m_2 + cz_1 + dz_2$. Is this correct?

My next step is to find the expected values, variances and covariance of the RHS and set them equal to the given moments for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$. This gives me the following system of non-linear equations:
\begin{align} a^2 + b^2 & = s_1^2 \\
c^2 + d^2 &= s_2^2\\
ac+bd &= s_{12} \end{align}

But how to continue from here? Set for example $a=1$ or $a=0$ and try to solve the system? Or am I thinking in the wrong direction? Thanks.

Comment: $L$ is lower triangular, allowing you to solve for $a$; that lets you solve for $c$, and then for $d$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you used the Cholesky decomposition where $L$ is a lower triangular matrix, meaning $b=0$. I hope this helps.